# xamarin forms livecast-like page-inline camera

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I was wondering if anyone here knows how to add a camera area like this one(similar to snapchat I guess) in Xamarin Forms (preferably,mainly with XAML)Camera area is suppose to have a livecast & it is going to be on iOS

needed this screen:

[image: needed this screen]

I tried Xam.Plugins.Media but couldn't manage to create the needed screen

Answer (score 0):

The media plugin, goes into the platform specific Camera Screen, takes a picture then returns. You can't put extra buttons on the screen in this way.

To get a video feed and manage the capture yourself, you will need to implement a lot of platform specific things.

**Android**

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/video/record_video/

**iOS** (Look at the AV samples)

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/ios/Media/